# Unable to add permissions to a newly created role in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to add a command to my bot that mutes people, and if the muted role doesnt exist, it creates it with the perms already implemented. My method doesnt work.

Here is my code:

```py
       if murole is None:
         guild = ctx.message.guild
         await guild.create_role(name="Muted")
         murole = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Muted")
         await murole.edit(permissions=discord.Permissions(send_messages=False, read_messages=True))

         await member.add_roles(murole)
```

and here's my error:
[sorry that i had to give an image instead of a copy, it would send a keyboard interrupt error and wont let me copy it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqRw2.png)

I tried to put the permissions directly into the create_role but that gave the same error

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Permissions` doesn't accept keyword arguments for the permissions. Instead, it takes an integer representing the bit string of permissions.  That's pretty useless to you, so you can write a helper function to create the object and then call the [`Permissions.update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Permissions.update) method, which does take keyword arguments

```
def make_permissions(**kwargs):
    perms = Permissions()
    perms.update(**kwargs)
    return perms
```